# Flickr API returning unavailable image Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, flickr

Hi I'm new to Windows Phone and the flickr API's.

I've been trying to get some images and display them on the panorama view with this code:

```
var baseUrl = string.Format(flickString, flickrAPIKey);
string flickrResult = await client.GetStringAsync(baseUrl);

FlickrData flickrApiData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FlickrData>(flickrResult);

if(flickrApiData.stat == "ok")
{
    foreach (Photo data in flickrApiData.photos.photo)
    {
        // To retrieve one photo
        // http://farm{farmid}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}{size}.jpeg

        //string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_o.jpeg";
        //string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_b.jpeg";
        string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{0}/{0}_{0}_n.jpeg";

        string baseFlickrUrl = string.Format(photoUrl,
            data.farm,
            data.server,
            data.id,
            data.secret);

        flickr1Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(baseFlickrUrl));

        break;
    }
}
```

I've tried trying different farms & servers etc but every time it still returns "This image is unavailable at this time". I dont know what I'm doing wrong here, appreciate some help.

Thanks

Comment: have you verified that the based url is correct return some results directly through flickr API

Comment: Hi I ran a search in flickr.photos.search and used the url given at the bottom of the screen as my flickString above.

Comment: have you tried to use the extra field in the flickr.photos.search API to get the image url directly

Comment: No I've only used the text field!

Comment: can you post the url you generated by using flickr.photo.search API

Comment: This is the url generated: string flickString = [link](https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=cc9babb2754c1d29837bea480c97013e&text=game+of+thrones&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&api_sig=bb86a60e9e42f31950bf53d25fc45f08)

Answer (score 1):

After Running your link, it turns out that the image extension should use jpg instead of jpeg

But I would strongly recommend you to use the extra field to get the respective url directly by using the extra attribute in the API

> extras (Optional)
>
> A comma-delimited list of extra information to fetch for each returned record.
>
> you can use either of those: url_sq, url_t, url_s, url_q, url_m, url_n, url_z, url_c, url_l, url_o

Comment: OK photourl (now is) string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}"; and added extras with the delimited list you gave (thanks). But image still unavailiable when I deploy to phone!

Comment: don't know why but all is working now...! Running the above code with this call string photoUrl = "http://farm{0}.staticflickr.com/{1}/{2}_{3}_n.jpeg..Go figure :-)